# How do you add an extra logger on play 2.0?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I been searching all over on the documentation of play 2.0 but I cannot find anything related to adding an extra logger.

Do you have any ideas of how to do this?

Is it done by adding an extra xml such as the JPA one or you may do it by creating a specific class?

Answer (score 2):

The configuration of the log is described [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/SettingsLogger). And yes you must write some xml for [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/documentation.html). I hope this  answer your question. If you want to change the log-implementation, I hope biesior is right.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to use XML. You have to *just* include Maven dependency in `project/Build.scala` file ie.

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.16"
)
```

then perform `play update` command in the terminal to fetch the jar from repository and that's all

Comment: I did that, but is there anything else that needs to be done? Does this redirect all the Logger statements to that file described in `log4j.properties`? Right now it's still creating the Application.log